# Defining a function with exec from inside a function in global environment

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I have a function that, when called, should define another function with use of `exec` and make this new function available for the main program. The mwe is the following.

Main program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from ext import makeF

makeF()
sayA()
```

External module:

```
def makeF():
    script="def sayA():\n\tprint 'Aah'"
    exec(script)
    sayA()
    return
```

What I want is to be able to call the inner function `sayA()` from the main program, so in this example the output should be

```
Aah
Aah
```

but instead it returns

```
Aah
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mwe.py", line 5, in <module>
    sayA()
NameError: name 'sayA' is not defined
```

which I kind of expected, so I replace the `exec(script)` line with `exec(script,globals)`, according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec), but instead I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mwe.py", line 4, in <module>
    makeF()
  File "/home/tomas/tests/ext.py", line 3, in makeF
    exec(script,globals,locals)
TypeError: exec: arg 2 must be a dictionary or None
```

I have the feeling I'm missing something pretty obvious here but I can't figure out. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have created the function inside `makeF` so it is not even visible in the scope of the external  module outside the function.

If you want to call it from main, `return sayA` :

```
def makeF():
    script="def sayA():\n\tprint('Aah')"
    exec(script)
    return sayA
```

Then in main:

```
f = makeF()
f()
```

To get the same behaviour in python3 where exec is no longer a statement but a function,you can use a lambda with a dict:

```
def makeF():
    d = {}
    "sayA = lambda: print('Aah')"
    exec("sayA = lambda: print('Aah')",d)
    return d["sayA"]

from ext import makeF

f = makeF()
f()
```

Comment: I tried running this code with python3 and it didn't work. Does it work for you?

Comment: works for me. I'm using python 2.7 though. Try it with `exec(script,globals())` or `exec(script,globals)`.

Comment: @TomCho, that is a hack. Whether it works for you or not the correct answer is the function is local to makeF, why hack something when you can simply return the function?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I didn't use that in my program. I actually used the same thing you suggested (no `globals` at all). I just made a sugestion for @browskie since apparently it didn't work for him on p3k. I just now realized that I forgot to reference him.

Comment: @TomCho, sorry yes, I did not see the other comment. I resumed the OP was using python2 as the function would not work at all in python 3 even in the local module.

Answer (score 4):

globals and locals() are functions, not dictionaries (though they *return* dictionaries).

But also, the way you were trying to invoke it, sayA is getting defined in locals(). Leave that out.

My version:

```
def makeF():
  script="def sayA():\n\tprint 'Aah'"
  #exec script in globals()
  exec(script, globals())
  #exec(script, globals(), locals())
  sayA()
  print globals()
  print locals()

makeF()
sayA()
```

Try out the commented out lines for contrast.